# RF Antenna Matching circuit and PCB design for 868 MHz SigFox device

Tags: rf, antenna

I'm designing a Sigfox sensor device based on **WISOL/SFM10R1** a SigFox verfied module by WiSOL and Atmega328.

I need to understand the parameters for 868 MHz RF Antenna Matching circuit and PCB trace width needed for the design. Following are few design layout and sketches.

I'm attaching a 50 Ω external antenna to uFL connector on board. Currently trace width of track from WiSOL module to uFL connector is 0.6096 mm

[image: RF PCB Layout]

Schematic:

[image]

Component value here are not correct and thats what I want to know the way to calculate it.
I'm not a RF expert its difficult subject for me.

I found one online calculator which I tried to use as a simple guide at
https://www.eeweb.com/tools/microstrip-impedance for calculating
trace-width. But as per my current parameters I'm getting trace-width of approx
3 mm which does not looks practical.

Parameters:

- Trace Thickness: 17umm (I hope this means copper thickness)
- Substrate Height: 1.6mm (This is probably PCB thickness.)
- Trace Width: ?
- Substrate Dielectric: 4 (I'm using FR4 PCB board so i guess this is ok)

**Freq: 868 MHz**

I have few questions here:

1. Which calculator should I go for - Microstrip, Symmetric stripline or embedded strip at the link I mentioned above, as im having double sided PCB and antenna trace is on top layer!
2. What will be the way to calculate value of component to match the antenna of 50  Ω
3. Does length of trace also matters?
4. Why I'm getting 3mm trace width? Where I am going wrong?
5. Whats the significance of those multiple vias added around antenna in most designs.
6. Any other suggestion to improve this antenna circuit design which should considered from certification point of view.

Comment: so, small things: 1. Units! It's "MHz", not "Mhz", please.

Comment: 2. these are six questions at once, maybe start with **one** question that you researched well – for example, if we focus on the first one, it shows you haven't done a bit of research on what "symmetric stripline" actually is, or else you'd already have ruled that out. Same for embedded strip line: If you have a many-layered board, sure, go for that. But you'd probably know if your board has more than 4 layers. Minutes of using google, less time than spent on asking here!

Comment: Re: 4. You're probably not going wrong. On thick FR4, multiple millimeters of trace width for microwave does sound realistic if you're doing microstrips.

Comment: Question 2. is too broad, also, multiple application notes and a large wealth of things you can find online.

Comment: Question 4.: that's probably even in the antenna's data sheet, or try searching for "vias ground plane antenna" on this site.

Comment: **So,** asked in this form, your question is *too broad*; please focus on one of your six questions and write down what you've researched so far. Thank you!

Comment: You must have a backside ground plane. The 1/16" dielectric causes the very thin trace width.  C9 and C8 are not "grounded", unless you add VIAS on both sides of each, these vias reaching DOWN to the underlying Ground plane. You can visualize that C8/C4/C9 as a candidate to become an CLC PI resonator. That is, C4 becomes a small inductor.

Comment: Dear @Marcus Muller, thank you for your generous comments and finding out first mistake!  I understand there are too many question, but I put on everything that i wanted to know. Instead of asking all separately its better to compose it all in one. I dont think my question is broad. All questions are related.

Comment: 1) As i already mentioned and you might have missed, Im not that good with RF design. But I want to learn. I am doing research. I dont think asking question is bad. Some time instead of reading lot of things its always better when some one gives us a small clue to enlighten about the fact. For example one small positive comment by @analogsystemsrf about Ground plane and VIAS cleared & started my thought process. Some time you know but still want to get confirmation from experts & thats why we come here. isnt it.? I hope the answer is Microstrip for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im posting the answer as suggested by WiSOL technical team. I'll update to it after fabrication and RF testing.
Component values are as follows:

[image]

L1 = 47nf for ESD , does not change RF maching

C4 = 100pf it offers 0ohm impedance.

C9=DNI

@Marcus Müller Imp part was PCB track which needed will be **Coplanar Wave** and not Microstrip.

So final calculation came as :
[image]

This tool can be downloaded from
[Saturn PCB Design Kit](http://www.saturnpcb.com/pcb_toolkit/)

Ground Vias will be needed along the side of pcb track line.

For now at least this is an appropriate answer for me.
Thank you all for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Your Pi matching network will look like this ( or similar values, that provide a high-Q??? resonance at 868 MHZ)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5Yu4I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @analogsystemsrf for your answer. Can you please explain about how the values are calculated.

Comment: @ Rajendra If you like an answer, its polite to upvote (or even "accept"; but wait another day on accepting). Consider that 1pFarad at 1GHz has -j160 ohms reactance. Since I don't know your antenna impedance, I simply used 1PF. Similarly, 1nanoHenry at 1GHz is +j6.3 ohms, 10nH is +j63 ohms. Clearly these are not resonant at 1GHz; how about 868? Nope, but you need to adjust the values. And "vias" in series with the two capacitors? And the inductance of that narrow-strip of Ground foil between the two capacitor-Ground nodes? Even PCB thermal-relief will affect the PI-network resonance.

Comment: Thank you @analogsystemsrf for the answer but I already tried upvoting your answer but i don't have much reputation to do that. I'll try to understand your comment and get back here if needed.